# Как раскрывать сайдбар на нужной мне странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть некий каталог товаров с подкатегориям. Каталог раскрываются при клике.При переходе на какую-либо страницу, каталог закрывается(сворачивается). Нужно сделать так, чтобы он не закрывался, в той подкатегории откуда был сделан переход. 
Ссылка на сайт: http://pavelbq1.beget.tech/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/ .

Comment: ответ простой - страницу не перезагружаем а лишь блок , применяем ajax , это снизит нагрузку на сервер и осуществится задуманное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый короткий путь решения я описал ниже. Я хочу объяснить логику, а реализация функции может отличаться. Вам нужно синхронизировать ваш активный URL и боковое меню.

**Решение:**

Сначала добавьте к `span` элементам меню аттрибут `data-url="кровельные-материалы"` согласно логике. Мы будем позже использовать этот аттрибут, чтобы найти `span`, который должен быть открыт при текущем URL.

При загрузке страницы вызовите функцию ниже, которая проверит какой URL сейчас активен, и кликнет по этому эл-ту автоматически, чтобы его открыть.

```
function openSideMenuBasedOnUrl() {

    // взять URL и перевести кириллицу
    var url = decodeURI(window.location.pathname);

    // заменить '/' вначале
    url = url.replace(/^\//, '');

    var urlParts = url.split('/');
    var firstUrlPart = urlParts[0];

    if (firstUrlPart) {

        // найти эл-т меню по аттрибуту
        var $span = $.find('#main span[data-url="' + firstUrlPart + '"]')[0];

        // тут нужно добавить проверку, что пункт меню не открыт уже

        // имитация клика
        if ($span) $span.click();
    }
}
```